# Visual Studio 2008 setup looking at wrong drive

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation

I'm trying to add a feature to VS 2008. However, the initial install was done with a DVD in drive D: ... I don't currently have the DVD, so I'm trying to do the updating using an .iso mounted as drive E: ... The VS setup program is not able to find the setup files.

Is there a way for me to tell VS 2008 setup to look for files in E: instead of D:? Maybe a registry or ini setting?

Edit:
The specific error message I got was: A selected drive is no longer valid

Comment: glad to see you accept your own answers, 69%, maybe you should take a look at your outstanding questions and accept some of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further googling, I found the answer. I had to uninstall VS 2008 SP1. Once I did that, the setup program allowed me to select the location of the installation files.

Comment: Wasted too much time... You could have simply used the media you tried to reinstall with, unless there were different versions

Comment: @Vecdid, you should try reading the question. I did not have the original media at the time since I was traveling. That is why I got the error. That was the whole point of the question.

Comment: I understand, but you need the files on your drive etc, if you launched from where the setup is on your drive it would have worked as well, as that was my point in my answer. You did say in your answer that you where able to select the path to the install files, so it is a given you have the install files, in which case no need for media, just launch from there directly and not the control panel, let alone having to uninstall sp1 and then having to reinstall. Just not a great use of your time is all. Glad to see your problem worked out. Take care

Answer (score 1):

you could remap your drive letters using the [disk management console](http://www.theeldergeek.com/disk_management.htm) so that your mounted iso is the D: drive. if an existing drive is currently mapped to D:, you'll have to remap that to something else first

Answer (score 1):

It is in the registry, try searching the registry for the path it is looking for.

Another thing you can do is run setup from your current VS 2008 location, instead of trying to launch it from control panel.

Comment: It is looking for d: ... impossible to search for in the registry because there are so many instances. Also tried your other suggestion with no luck

Comment: If you launch setup from the original disc for Visual Studio it should work, done it plenty of times, if not what is the error?

Comment: also in regards to searching the registry, if you click add/remove features from the control panel when it asks for the media you should see the old path to setup, search for the whole path, if not forget it then, but also try hitting browse, then it may say the path.

Comment: The error you added to your question is not an error you would get trying to install from your current media. I was looking as to WHY you cannot add remove using the setup file located on the original media. Also if you do not know how to install off the hard drive by clicking setup you can burn it all to DVD and launch setup from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how or if you can change where setup looks for the files.

One thing you could do though is change the mount point of the ISO to D: instead of E:.  This could be done on a temporary basis until you've completed adding the feature.  Go to

- Control Panel
- Administrative Tools
- Computer management
- Select the Disk Management Node
- Change the associated drive letters

Comment: @Keith, can you be more specific?  Are the files in the same location when you remap the drives?

Comment: I dont know if they are in the same location. I dont have the DVD with me.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by a bug in VS SP1 as described at
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/487382/installing-visual-studio-2008-sp1-disables-ability-to-make-changes-to-visual-studio-installed-features

The directions there say to install the hotfix KB97957.

Fixed my problem and a lot easier that uninstalling SP1 (after installing the KB it just asks you where your install files are located)